# Write after end error when response.end() is called while creating a server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a newbie to StackOverflow. I have just started learning Node.js. As such I have been experimenting with inbuilt methods like createServer and response.end(). I wrote the following code snippet with the intention of trying out everything that I have learned in a single operation.

```js
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {
    'content-type': 'text/html'
  });
  response.write('<b>Hello</b> World<br/>');
  response.write('Type of request parameter = ' + typeof request);
  response.write('<br/>Request URL = ' + request.url);

  if (request.url != '/') {
    var q = url.parse(request.url, true).query;
    var date = q.date + '&nbsp;' + q.month;
    response.write('<br/>Date = ' + date);
    var q2 = url.parse(request.url).query;
    response.write('<br/>Date2 = ' + q2);

  }

  fs.readFile('TextFile1.txt', function(err, data) {
    if (err)
      return console.error('<br/>' + err);
    response.write('<br/>' + data);
    response.end();
  });

  // response.end();
}).listen(8083);

console.log('Server running at localhost:8083');
```

When I run the above code snippet, it gets executed flawlessly and returns the output as expected when I access the server. However, if I uncomment the line **response.end()** just before the end of the createServer method and subsequently comment out the existing response.end() call, I face the error 'Error: write after end'.

What is the difference between the two scenarios? The call to response.end() is made in both cases with different outcomes. I tried searching online for the explanation, but the answers were related to asynchronous execution which I found a little difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node is asynchronous. When you uncomment response.end() just before createServer method ends, node ends up executing that line before it reaches the response.write() inside your fs.readFile() scope. And hence it throws a error saying write after end, because respond.end() has already executed by the time your response.write() is executed.

Comment: Thanks @Sashi. Does that imply that adding response.end() call inside the callback function ensures its execution after the file contents are written into the response?

Comment: Yup that's right. The callback function passed to fs.readFile() will only be executed after the file is read. By adding response.end() inside the callback function you can ensure that the file contents are read, the contents are written to the response (res.write) and then the response is sent (res.end).

Answer (score 0):

you can have a look at https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-async-programming-in-node-js/  to get a little more about asynchronous programming(like nodejs) vs synchronous programming(like java).

Comment: Thanks @Aryan Malik for the helpful blog post.